# Yii count model with relation

Tags: php, mysql, yii, count, relation

I have a model Aziende, that is related (1:N) to anther model called Annunci, like this:

```
'annunci' => array(self::HAS_MANY,'Annunci','azienda_id'),
```

I would like to count how many record does really have this relation, in mySql I will do:

```
SELECT count( * )
FROM `aziende` a
JOIN annunci an ON an.azienda_id = a.id
```

How can i do this with Yii AR Model?

PS: I tried to look out conditional query, but i can't find my way.

Answer (score 6):

In Yii relation type, we have STAT which do this for you. In relations():

```
'annunciCount' => array(self::STAT,'Annunci','azienda_id'),
```

and in controller:

```
$model= Model::model()->findAll();
echo 'The Number is: '.$model->annunciCount;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited:**

```
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->condition = 'annunci.id IS NOT null';

    $aziendeList= Aziende::model()->with('annunci')->findAll($criteria);        
    $count = count($aziendeList); // Count how many "Azienda" have at least one "Annunci"
```

Comment: Hi, maybe I've explained wrong, I don't need to know how many "Annunci" are inerted for one "Azienda", but how many "Azienda" have at least one "Annunci". How can I achieve this?

Comment: oohh, i'm sorry. I edited my answer. does this solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the

```
getRelated()
```

**From Yii api:**

Returns the related record(s). 
This method will return the related record(s) of the current record. 
If the relation is HAS_ONE or BELONGS_TO, it will return a single object 
or null if the object does not exist. If the relation is HAS_MANY or MANY_MANY, 
it will return an **array** of objects or an empty array.

You can just use the "count($related)" or "sizeOf($related)" to get the count.

**Yii api link:**

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#getRelated-detail

Comment: Maybe I've explained wrong. This method will return the related record(s) of the current record. Instead I would like to count how many record (Aziende) have at least one relation (Annunci). Thanks anyway.